# Como corrigir seleção de arquivos para download no Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Bom dia, o servidor de hospedagem da empresa que trabalho fez uma atualização e resultou em vários problemas para meu site. Um deles foi com relação à upload/seleção de arquivos. Em síntese: quando tento inserir uma mídia, apresenta "erro de http". Outra coisa que aparentemente possui relação direta com o problema é o fato de que quando eu vou no campo de mídias não é listado nada, nenhum arquivo.
Sugestões de onde começar?

Comment: Voce tem acesso ao log de erros do servidor? Provável que tenha mensagens mais úteis lá.

Comment: ver as permissões das pastas de upload

Comment: Desculpem pela demora, mas estou em contato com o pessoal da hospedagem. Creio que o problema seja mesmo de permissões, mas vou aguardar uma resposta deles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução. Como foi mencionado, o problema era de permissões, só que não na pasta /uploads mas sim na pasta /wp-content.
Agradeço pela ajuda de todos.